# command 'use' dont work in a custom function PHP but work on a template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a problem with this command. Im using Vimeo's API to obtain the thumbnail and it works:
I am working in drupal 7, using Vimeo's API and php and works fine.

```
require '/home/SSSSS/www/html/vendor/vimeo/vimeo-api/autoload.php';
    use Vimeo\Vimeo;
    $client = new Vimeo("XXXXX", "YYYYY", "ZZZZ");
    $response = $client->request('/videos/AAAAA/pictures', array(), 'GET');
    $imgg= $response["body"]["data"][0][sizes][0][link];
```

The problem is when i try to do a function with this code.

Make a syntax error on **use Vimeo\Vimeo;**

Dont recognize this route or code, why? I dont understand, why works on a template.php but dont work on my module's function?

[image: error]

Thanks

PD: I focus the problem. the problem is that dont recognize the function 'require' inside a function.
I solved the problem putting the line
**require '/home/SSSSS/www/html/vendor/vimeo/vimeo-api/autoload.php';**
out of my function, in the top of my .module.

Any way to do all in inside the function?

Comment: Quote the actual error message, instead of giving us _“Make a syntax error”_

Comment: You need to show more of your code and the actual error message for this to make sense for anybody here. I'd suggest you to trim down your code until it is just enough to reproduce the error. Then share with us the trim-down source code with the actual error message.

Comment: We'd like to help. But you need to show enough for people to effectively help you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the `require` call is the issue here. I'd guess it's probably a problem with your `use` call. And there is no point to put it inside any function at all.

### What? I don't need the library for every call. Why put `use` on top?

First you must understand what [`use`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) statement does:

> The ability to refer to an external fully qualified name with an alias, or importing, is an important feature of namespaces.

**It does not really call or load anything** on its own. It only provides a way for you to write less code in referencing a particular namespace. For example, this standalone PHP works without the namespace or class even exists:

```php
<?php

use This\Do\Not\Exists;

echo Exists::class;
```

Result:

```
This\Do\Not\Exists
```

The `use` statement works on the file scope. There is no point having a `use` statement within a function scope. That's why it is not valid. And having a `use` statement in a function would produce an error like this:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /path/to/your/code.php on line XXX
```

The solution is really simple. You can move the `use` statement(s) out of the function and to the top of your `.module` file. This would simply declare an alias to the supposedly valid namespace. The Vimeo\Vimeo class won't be loaded. Thus the autoloader do not needed to be `require` before your `new Vimeo("XXXXX", "YYYYY", "ZZZZ")` call.

Putting the use statement on top of PHP files (after `namespace` line) is, in fact, the recommended code style in [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) guideline.

---

**Note:** there is no problem in require the Vimeo autoloader on the top of your module file, either. That is just a small piece of program to automatically load the correct PHP file **when a class is called**. You can put both lines to the top of your module file.

Comment: yes, thanks so much!. Like i said (and edit my post) i solve the problem putting the **require** out of the function on the top of my module file. The **use** statement I have left it inside the function and works fine.